# search read sql data to textbox in vb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

it show even when i have data inside my database[invalid attempt to read when no data is present] 
i was hoping to show details in textbox with txtid.text inserted

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


     Dim con As New SqlConnection
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
     Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    Try

        con.ConnectionString = "Server=KAVIER;Database=vb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con


        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM music where mus_id  = '" & txtid.Text & "' "
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader() 'corrected my previous mistake

        If rd.HasRows Then

            txtartist.Text = rd.Item("customer")
            txtid.Text = rd.Item("album")
            txtgenre.Text = rd.Item("genre")
            hided.Text = rd.Item("music_copies")
            txtprice.Text = rd.Item("price")
            txttotal.Text = txtprice.Text * txtwalkinquantities.Text

        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: the `.ExecuteReader` line should come after the `.CommandText =` line    ie.You must set the commandtext before executing the executereader call

Comment: it works! thanks but another problem,it shows[invalid attempt to read when no data is present] but there're data in my database

Comment: Read this : [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM music where mus_id  = '" & txtid.Text & "' "
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If rd.read Then

        txtartist.Text = rd.Item("customer")
        txtid.Text = rd.Item("album")
        txtgenre.Text = rd.Item("genre")
        hided.Text = rd.Item("music_copies")
        txtprice.Text = rd.Item("price")
        txttotal.Text = txtprice.Text * txtwalkinquantities.Text

    End If
```

replace `rd.HasRows` with  `rd.read`

Comment: OMG!!! it workss =)))) thankss alot!!struggled for days just because of the .hasrow